# How to check if an object is an Enum

Tags: c#, .net, types

I have a SQL query builder method:

```
public static string PreprocessSQL(string sql, params object[] args)
```

Provided that the sql parameter is "String.Format friendly", this method loops through the params and plugs them into the query string, doing whatever needs to be done based on the type of the argument - convert a null to string "NULL", surround a string with single quotes, etc.

Now the problem is with enums. I need a logic that checks if the type of current  args[i] is Enum, and if so, convert it to int. How to do this check? My first guess, for some reason, doesn't work:

```
if(args[i].GetType() == typeof(Enum)) {
    converted.Add((int)args[i]);
}
```

The above condition apparently gets evaluated as false.

My enum class is:

```
public enum Priority {
    Low,
    Normal,
    High
}
```

If a pass a value of Priorty.Normal to this method, I figured the "value" is Normal, and the type of that value is Priority, which autmatically inherits from Enum, so I'm done. Turns out it's not that simple, and from what I can tell, it looks like the type of the value Normal is actually Priority.Normal

Now I could explicitly check for all the enums I'm using in my project, it's only 2 classes actually, but would that even work?

```
if(args[i].GetType() == typeof(Priority)) { ... }
```

I mean, if type of args[i] is Priority.Normal, this would too evaluate as false.

How do I check an unknown `object o` has the type of a enumeration class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Type of Enum witnin class through C# reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408800/getting-type-of-enum-witnin-class-through-c-sharp-reflection)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a78445ca-c004-4612-938b-0a70734f817e/enum-gettype?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check IsEnum property.

```
args[i].GetType().IsEnum
```

Or

```
if(args[i] is Enum)
{
}
```

Or

```
bool isEnum = typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(args[i].GetType());
```

Or

```
bool isEnum = typeof(Enum).IsInstanceOfType(o);
```

Comment: @DanAndrews And I think you're pointing to java. In .Net we use `is` keyword for the same thing. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: You're right, I'm still sleeping.  That's the problem with being a code monkey.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 bool isEnum = o is Enum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `IsEnum` property of `System.Type`

```
bool isEnum = typeof(YourType).IsEnum
```