# Get inner type from string

Tags: c#, types, enums

Imagine I have the following namespace:

```
namespace One.Two.Three {
    public static class ExampleClass{
        public .....
        public enum ExampleOne { one, two three }
        public enum ExampleTwo { four, five, six }
        public enum ExampleThree { random, text, this, is }

    }
}
```

How can I get the Type by a string?

With the help of [Getting Type of Enum witnin class through C# reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408800/getting-type-of-enum-witnin-class-through-c-sharp-reflection)
I have tried the following, but without any result:

```
public Type returnEnumType(String name){
    String nameSpace = (typeof(One.Two.Three.ExampleClass)).FullName;
    Type type = Type.GetType(nameSpace + name);

    return type
}

Type.GetType("One.Two.Three.ExampleClass.ExampleOne"); //neither works
```

What am I missing here?

@edit Not a duplicate. I am not trying to parse my enumerator, I am trying to get the type based on a String.

Comment: Not a duplicate, not trying to parse into an enumerator.. Just trying to get the type.

Comment: you can easily get the full name using `typeof(ExampleClass.ExampleOne).FullName`

Comment: If i know the name of the enumerator in advance yes, but I do not..

Comment: I already know that, see my code. It is literally in there. That is not what I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Type.GetType("One.Two.Three.ExampleClass+ExampleOne");`

Reason: `ExampleOne` is an inner type, therefore you need to use the plus sign `+` instead of the dot.